# Aurelia + Redux performance

Tags: javascript, redux

I use Aurelia on a daily basis. Recently, I have been looking into using Redux (i.e. I built a couple of small trial apps using Aurelia+Redux) and have been really impressed (my development workflow and clarity of reasoning about my application is greatly improved). I have decided that I would like to start working it in to real-world applications.

With that said, I have a concern regarding performance (I have looked around at posts about performance but haven't seen my issue address directly). I think this question is not specific to Aurelia, more a question about Redux and using it with non-react libraries.

Let me preface my question with my understanding of Redux (perhaps my question is really arising from a flawed understanding?). Essentially, the way I understand Redux is that there is a store (a javascript object) and a reducing function. Now, the reducing function may be defined as a tree of functions (each responsible for modifying a specific branch of the overall store), however, in reality, Redux receives a single reducing function (it has no way of knowing how many functions were composed to create this single function).

The way I am using Redux is like so (just an example):

```
@inject(Store)
export class TodosListCustomElement {
    constructor(store) {
        this.store = store;
    }

    activate() {
        this.update();
        this.unsubcribe = this.store.subscribe(this.update.bind(this));
    }

    deactivate() {
        this.unsubcribe();
    }

    update() {
        const newState = this.store.getState();

        this.todos = newState.todos;
    }

    toggleCompleted(index) {
        this.store.dispatch({
            type: UPDATE_TODO,
            payload: {
                index,
                values: {
                    isCompleted: !this.todos[index].isCompleted
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Essentially, each component down the component tree, subscribes itself to store changes and refreshes the data it needs from the store.

My concern is that there seems to be a lot happening on each published action. For example, say I have a large application with a similarly large store and reducer tree. Suppose there is some throttled textbox that dispatches changes to a single text field (in one item of a list) in the store every 250 ms. That would mean that as a user types, the entire reducer function is executed every 250ms (which could mean executing quite a large number of its descendant reducers) as well as all the subscribing functions are executed as well. Basically, it seems like there is a lot of overhead to change even the smallest part of the store.

Contrast this with a standard binding (in Aurelia) where there is just a single bound function (mutation observer) that needs to execute every 250ms to update the model...

Since I am new to Redux, I guess there is a good chance that I am naively misunderstanding something etc. I apologize in advance and hope to be corrected/put on the right track (because my limited experience using Redux has been very enjoyable).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You're actually describing the situation pretty well, on multiple levels.

First, the React-Redux bindings do a lot of work to ensure that connected components only actually re-render when some of the data relevant to a given component has changed.  This is done by having a connected component supply a function called `mapStateToProps`, which extracts the data that component wants from the store state.  The wrapper components generated by `connect` will re-run their `mapState` functions after each dispatch, and do shallow comparisons between the latest returned values and the previous returned values to see if the data has changed.  That cuts down on the amount of actual UI updates that need to be done.

There's also tradeoffs involved in how you handle connected forms.  Yes, dispatching an action for every single keystroke is likely to be inefficient overall.  I personally use a React form wrapper component that buffers those text input changes locally, and only dispatches a debounced Redux action after the user is done typing.

The React-Redux bindings were recently rewritten, and are now primarily based on memoized selector functions rather than having most of the logic inside of React components.  I don't know how the Aurelia bindings are put together, but I suspect that they could probably leverage a lot of the work that's been done to optimize the React bindings.

You may be interested in some of the articles I have on Redux-related performance.  See the Redux FAQ question at http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/Performance.html#performance-scaling , as well as the articles in my React/Redux links list at https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/react-performance.md#redux-performance .

Comment: Thanks for your response. Correct me if I am wrong, what I understand from your response is that there are many strategies to optimize render operations using Redux + React. However, there is no strategy to optimize the overhead inherent in Redux itself, namely, that on every change to the store, the entire reducer function needs to be run (which, in large applications, may mean calling hundreds of functions or more), is that correct?

Comment: Correct.  Redux itself is _really_ simple - it doesn't provide a way to "subscribe to a specific slice of state", or do any diffing of values.  It simply calls the reducer, saves whatever it returns, and runs all subscription callbacks.  That said, I wouldn't worry about reducer performance as a bottleneck.  That's generally going to be some function calls with switch statements and lookup tables - not very expensive. If you _are_ concerned, there's approaches to ensure chunks of reducer code are only run if needed.